# Manifold meaning

Tags: meaning

This is a sentence

> After doping, the conductivity of this semiconductor device is increased **manifold**.

What's the meaning of "manifold" in this context.

Manifold: [Other meanings here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/manifold)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Manifold* is built along the same pattern as *threefold*, *fivefold*, and *thousand[fold](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-fold)*, used to describe an increase/decrease of three, five, or a thousand times. In  this context, *manifold* simply means "many times, numerous, multiple."

In online dictionaries llike the one you consulted, you'd almost have to look at the word's [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/manifold) [word history, provenance] to figure that out, since the modern usage leans much more toward "various, varied, complicated."

Comment: I would feel a lot better about this answer if you included the fact that the word is basically a mistake in this context and register. It really should be *manyfold*, not *manifold*. Compare recent usage in Ngrams or Google Scholar where a purely quantifiable increase is being discussed. Natural speakers in formal registers use manyfold. Recent examples of *manifold* being used this way are predominantly from former British colonies. There may be a difference in acceptability between Britons and Americans, but I didn't see it in the examples I looked at.

Comment: [NYT style guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=o2E5BgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT291&ots=AiXGDsfoo3&dq=Manyfold%2C%20manifold%20style%20guide&pg=PT291#v=onepage&q=Manyfold,%20manifold%20style%20guide&f=false)

Comment: To me, _manyfold_ sounds 19th c. and _manifold_ King James version. I would never use either. Since "multiple" is still an accepted meaning of _manifold_, however, one could consider this usage as moribund, but not quite wrong. You're right about register though. I got a chuckle out of _semiconductor_ and _manifold_ appearing in the same sentence.